# show that $T$ is a Fredholm operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

let $E$ be a Banach space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$

assume that there exists $S \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $I - ST$ and $I-TS$ are both compact operators.

show that $T$ is a Fredholm operator.

by Fredholm's Alternative I can say that both $ST$ and $TS$ are fredholm operators, this also tells us that if such an $S$ exists then it has to be a Fredholm operator.

can anyone plot me a sketch of proof or recommends me a good reference where I can find the proof of this proposition ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\ker(T) \subset \ker(ST)$ and that $\ker(T^*) \subset \ker((TS)^*)$.

---

If we want to avoid the properties of the adjoint, here's another way to see that the image of $T$ is of finite codimension.

Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that image of the map $T: E \to E$ does not have finite codimesion.  Consider the quotient map $P:E \to E/\operatorname{im}(T)$;  note that $P$ is not compact and that $\operatorname{im}(T) \subset \ker(P)$, which means that $PT = 0$.

Now, note that $I - TS$ is compact.  It follows that $P(I - TS)$ must also be compact.  However, 
$$
P(I - TS) = PI - (PT)S = P
$$
and as we said earlier, $P$ is not compact.  Thus, we have a contradiction.

Comment: thanks for the answer, one inclusion is used to show that the kernel is finite dimensional (directly) and the other is used to show that the co-kernel is finite dimensional as well (using the fact that $\ker{(T^{*})} = \overline{\operatorname{Im}(T)}^{\perp}$), is this right ?

Comment: That's exactly it.  By the way, it's a lowercase k for `\ker`.